# What are the optimal tools for creating my own personal fund-tracking app?

Tags: database

So I'm familiar with programming, but am not exactly a professional one. I don't mind a bit of practice though, as I want to code my own web app for tracking my earnings and spendings. What are the optimal tools for that? By 'optimal' I mean not too complex ones, but at the same time not some simple visual constructors.

Here's what it needs:

- A simple page for input;
- 2 databases, one for money earned and one for money spent;
- The DBs are very basic XY ones;
- The main feature is building graphs out of the database tables I select in real time.

And here's the question:

- What is the best way to make the DBs? A friend of my told me that SQLs are way to complex for this task and suggested to put the data in JSON format. Will I be able to put this data in, let's say, an Excel file if I needed to?
- What is the best language to choose so I can work with this data? I don't mind picking some library to ease the task. At first I thought of Python, but a friend suggested to use jQuery, which is more familiar to me.

Please don't suggest getting someone else's app, I'm interested in making this on my own. Hope I made the question clear enough, pleas let me know if it's not. Thanks for your time!

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: There's no "best way", there's just ways that work well for you in your very particular situation. As to what those are, you'll need to find out by *trying things*. Try SQL. Try Excel. Try other things like MongoDB or whatever. There's a multitude of tools to pick from, and tons of documentation and examples for each.